# Error running '__rvm_make -j10' while installing ruby 2.6.5 on mac

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, rvm

I am trying to install the ruby 2.6.5 on mac having m1 pro chip but it's giving error of "__rvm_make -j10".

I tried to google but won't find error with "__rvm_make -j10". there is one question with the same error on stackoverflow and i tried the same method but it won't worked too.

i tried "rvm install 2.6.5  --with-out-ext=fiddle"
i tried with open ssl 1.0 too, but not any one worked.

```
sammalik@Sams-MacBook-Pro rubyporgram % rvm install 2.6.5
ruby-2.6.5 - #removing src/ruby-2.6.5 - please wait
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/13.0/arm64/ruby-2.6.5.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for osx.
Updating certificates bundle '/opt/homebrew/etc/openssl@1.1/cert.pem'
Requirements installation successful.
Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/sammalik/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-2.6.5 - #downloading ruby-2.6.5, this may take a while depending on your connection...
ruby-2.6.5 - #extracting ruby-2.6.5 to /Users/sammalik/.rvm/src/ruby-2.6.5 - please wait
ruby-2.6.5 - #configuring - please wait
ruby-2.6.5 - #post-configuration - please wait
ruby-2.6.5 - #compiling - please wait
Error running '__rvm_make -j10',
please read /Users/sammalik/.rvm/log/1668327329_ruby-2.6.5/make.log
There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.
```

Comment: please read `/Users/sammalik/.rvm/log/1665071379_ruby-2.6.5/make.log` as indicated in the log. It contains details about what went wrong.

Comment: i tired but not able to understand what it saying

Comment: You could (and this might sound like a wild idea but follow me here), well, you could add the contents of the file to your question as others might understand it...

Comment: I have recently encountered this issue. I could not find any solution so I switched to `rbenv` to unblock myself.

Comment: @HolgerJust I appreciate the fact that you want clarity, but no need to be spicy about it. :)  Also, yes,  post the 12k line error message. ;)

Answer (score 5):

Ruby 2.6.x is no longer supported on any Mac that has version 14 or higher of Apple's command line tools, which would be the case on macOS Ventura (13.0). Assuming you have Homebrew installed, you can check which version you have by running `brew config`, and then look towards the bottom for the lines that starts with `CLT:` and `Xcode:`

Ruby 2.6 reached end of life in March 2022, so it should not be used in production for security reasons. A lot of people get stuck because they think they **have** to use the version of Ruby that's specified in the project's `.ruby-version` and/or `Gemfile`. Instead, it's recommended to update the project to a newer version.

In most cases, it would be as easy as following these steps:

1. Install Ruby 2.7.7
2. Replace "2.6.x" with "2.7.7" in `.ruby-version` and `Gemfile`, and any other file where the Ruby version is specified (except `Gemfile.lock` because it should never be edited manually)
3. Run `bundle install`
4. Update any gems if necessary
5. Run your tests and make sure your app still works

Now that you know the recommended approach, let's go over 2 solutions in case you have a special need to use Ruby 2.6 before you update to 2.7.7:

- Install Ruby with Homebrew
- Downgrade to version 13.4 of the command line tools

### Install Ruby with Homebrew

1. Install [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) if you haven't already
2. Install Ruby 2.6.10: `brew install ruby@2.6`
3. Follow the instructions for setting your `PATH`. For example, Homebrew will say something like this:

```
By default, binaries installed by gem will be placed into:
  /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/bin

You may want to add this to your PATH.

If you need to have ruby first in your PATH, run:
  echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
```

The reason this works is because this is a pre-built version of Ruby that was compiled with version 13.3 of the command line tools. However, note that it's not officially supported.

Note that you'll need to disable RVM or any other version manager you might have used before. And you'll only be able to use 2.6.10 with this setup. You won't be able to switch to other versions that you might have installed with RVM or another version manager.

This is meant as a temporary solution so that you can run your project with 2.6.10 and then update it to 2.7.7. Also, note that either way, you will need to update your project to at least 2.6.10. There's absolutely no reason to use 2.6.5. You should always make sure your apps are running the latest version in a series. For 2.6, it's 2.6.10, for 2.7, it's 2.7.7, then 3.0.5, and 3.1.3.

### Downgrade to version 13.4 of the command line tools

This is not possible on macOS Ventura (13.0), so don't waste your time trying. If you're on macOS Monterey, you can download version 13.4 of the command line tools from [Apple's developer site](https://developer.apple.com/download/all/?q=xcode), and then install them.

Comment: yeah that's right, but this installation gives error on only mac specially on m1 chip processor but it's working fine on same os with intel chip and other os too.

Comment: I have mac with intel chip and I can not install ruby 2.6.8 for some reason, I have Ventura 13.2 @AaquibJawed

Comment: As I mentioned, it is no longer possible to install Ruby 2.6.x even on Intel Macs if you have version 14 or higher of Xcode and/or the command line tools, which would be the case on Ventura. It's not possible to downgrade to v13 on Ventura. Here are your options: https://www.rubyonmac.dev/how-to-install-ruby-2-6-on-macos-13-ventura

Answer (score 4):

The following works fine with macOS Ventura 13.1. You have to choose an older openssl version e.g. openssl@1.0.2t

1. Make sure you have home-brew installed `/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"`
2. (Optional) Check if you already have openssl versions installed via home-brew. Uninstall not ncessary versions `brew uninstall openssl`
3. Install openssl via home-brew: `brew install openssl@1.0.2t`
4. Check the path where your local home-brew packages go. In my case it is /usr/local/opt/openssl@1.0/.
5. Install ruby with rvm `rvm install 3.1.3 --with-openssl-dir=/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.0/`

Comment: you can install ruby 3 without openssl flag

Comment: You can also use a higher openssl version. Shout out to [this comment showing a more explicit sequence of commands](https://github.com/rbenv/homebrew-tap/issues/9#issuecomment-1683015411): `brew install openssl@3; rvm install 3.2.2 --with-openssl-dir=$(brew --prefix openssl@3)`.

Answer (score 3):

On Mac Ventura 13.4.1

Problem seems to be that rvm is not referencing the correct openssl library. To fix we need to locate the openssl directory... if installed via homebrew it's likely here `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openssl@3`

The simply rerun the the rvm install command with the override pointing to the located directory

```
rvm install 3.2.2 --with-openssl-dir=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openssl@3
```

Install should complete easily.

Answer (score 0):

I've been through a similar problem in Ubuntu 22.10. Here are some points that may help you:

1. Your OpenSSL may be too updated and probably has some breaking changes that don't allow some of your ruby C files to be compiled. Download a previous version at [OpenSSL website](https://www.openssl.org/source/old/), install it in a different location than your current version and use `rvm install --with-openssl-dir=<old-openssl-dir> 2.6.5` as mentioned in Chris' answer.
2. Instead of using `--with-openssl-dir` option, you could add your old OpenSSL `/bin` and `/include` files directly in environment variables in your `rvm` command, like this: `PATH=<old-openssl-bin-path>:$PATH C_INCLUDE_PATH=<old-openssl-include-path>:/usr/include rvm install 2.6.5`. This could be useful in the case that `--with-openssl-dir` option isn't available for some reason. You also need to create links to the `/lib` files in your old OpenSSL folder. You'll probably find paired files like `libssl.so` and `libssl.so.1.1`. You can just move the version-named files into `/usr/lib`(or similar for macos), otherwise when you execute `openssl` command from your old OpenSSL folder, it will probably raise an error saying that openssl can't find libraries. If you choose to use this method, make sure that your rvm user bin files (at `~/.rvm/usr/bin`) don't contain any files that may mess the ruby installing (like another `openssl` executable). You may get rid of this folder using `rvm pkg remove`.
3. Another possible solution is changing your `gcc` version. My OS came with gcc version 12.2.0, which comes with a [change in computer gotos](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-12/changes.html) that failed my make step. To find errors in your ruby installation, check the `make.log` file specified at the `rvm` command error message and look for lines like this:

[image: make.log error line example]

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and I got the solution [here](https://github.com/rvm/ubuntu_rvm/issues/67#issuecomment-1410267352)

you just have to downgrade openssl by

```
sudo apt install libssl-dev=1.1.1l-1ubuntu1.4  openssl=1.1.1l-1ubuntu1.4
```